# Custom tabulation in enumeration

Tags: numbering, lyx, lists

I want to make a simple document with some exercises and I need to make a list. What I expected is something like MS Word, with a tabulation at left. But I get this:

LyX:

[image: this is on LyX]

PDF:

[image: this is on the PDF]

I want to get something like this (with numbers and characters):

[image: imagen]

I mean when I put a list with numbers or bullets, they're aligned at left and not with some space (or tabulation) to be into the paragraph.

So, what I mean, how can I solve it?

I'm using the latest version of LyX and MiKTeX, and Windows (I guess it's the same for GNU/Linux).

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The first two images show the LyX input and PDF output. They match, so the output is "as expected". Now you mention that instead you want a list with bullets (in the picture), or is it numbers (in the text)?

Comment: I want to get the same align at left with numbers and bullets (the last image is from my Calculus profesor's excercises pdf).

Comment: Now you're talking about alignment, while I was asking about the numbering of the items. Two completely different things. Do you know how to insert a bulleted list in LyX?

Comment: I think you don't really understand what I want. If I put a number list, I get a list which is not aligned as I want (last image, but with numbers instead of bullets). And the same thing happens when I use bullets.

Comment: If I don't understand it, many others might also not. You should explain yourself better in the question.

Comment: I'm going to edit the ask, then.

Comment: @Werner It's edited. is it a better explanation?

Comment: It's not you, it's me. I want to understand, but the pictures aren't helping... So your problem is the indentation of the text that does not form part of the list?

Comment: I think yes. I mean... When you create a list in Word, you get a list (no matter if it's with numbers or bullets in this case), with a simple indent at left, and when you finish that list, the text goes back to the default position. I don't get it in LyX but the output of the first 2 images.

I want to get what I show in the third picture, which is made by a profesor of Calculus at my university.

Comment: That indentation is standard for TeX - something MS Word does not do. If you want to remove all of the regular paragraph indentations, then add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to you Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble. If you want to selectively remove the indentation of a specific paragraph, place your cursor in the paragraph and follow Edit > Paragraph Settings... and uncheck "Indent Paragraph".

Comment: i think you want to use an `enumerate` environment -- `\begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}` -- with each item introduced by `\item`.  numbering restarts with 1 every time the environment is restarted.

Comment: barbarabeeton that's what I'm using, but not as I want :)
@Werner yes! That's it! Sorry for my bad english/explanation. Very thankful for your help!

Comment: The indentation of list is controlled by such lengths like `\leftmargin`, `\itemindent` etc. The `enumitem` package provides some means to control them

Comment: @adolphenom you might be interested in LyX's mailing list for Spanish speakers. To subscribe, send a blank email to lyx-es-subscribe@lists.lyx.org . To then ask questions, send an email to lyx-es@lists.lyx.org . We are an informal group and the mailing list is low-traffic.

Comment: Christian, I have that package installed, but I cannot make it work.

Comment: @scottkosty thank you, I'll be into the list later!

Answer (score 1):

The indentation you're referring to deals with the paragraphs rather than the list items themselves. This is standard for TeX - something MS Word does not do.

If you want to remove all of the regular paragraph indentations, then add `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to you Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble. If you want to selectively remove the indentation of a specific paragraph, place your cursor in the paragraph and follow Edit > Paragraph Settings... and uncheck "Indent Paragraph":

[image]

This would be equivalent to inserting `\noindent` in an ERT as part of the paragraph text.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering this question. I tried, but as I have by default the indentation for all the document, when I do that, it checks again itself, and it's kind of boring. 

By the way, with what you told me about before that, it works as well as I wanted at first time. Now, the document has the style I want. 

I'll try again, I promise.

Thank you, Werner, for your help!